# Angular - Calling method on service from component returns undefined

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5

I have this service in the services file which is an http call.

```
    export class BackendServices {
      addons: IAddons[];   
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
        this.getWorkOrders();
      }
     getAddons() {
      this.http.get<IAddons>(this.BASE_URL + '/addons/')
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.addons = data;
      });
    }
```

COMPONENT PART
Then from my main component I have a button which calls the modal dialog. Here is the code of the main component:

```
export class OrdersComponent { 
openAddonsDialog() {
    let dialogRef = this.pickAddonsDialog.open(PickaddonsComponent);
  }
}
```

And then I am calling the getAddons method which is on the service from the constructor of the dialog.
I am just wondering how do we make the modal dialog open only when the addons property has received data from the http call.

```
export class PickaddonsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public bs: BackendServices) {
        this.bs.getAddons();
    }
```

But it says this.service.getAddons() is undefined. Read a lot about this on stackoverflow, tried quite a few steps from different posts, but none helped me so far.

Comment: Can you share error sceenshot

Comment: @ShashankVivek , Hello I have added the screenshot

Comment: Your error is for `addons: IAddons[]` and not `getAddons()`. If ur image is correct, can you check whether `addons` is not `private`

Comment: No it is just addons:IAddons[];

Comment: what about `getAddons()` ? the error is for `addons` and not `getAddons()`. Can you share your code. Your screenshot contradicts with your question

Comment: @ShashankVivek, I got more code added, please have a look at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170945/discussion-between-shashank-vivek-and-sumchans).

Comment: try initializing it. addons: IAddons[]=[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that initialized `BackendService` has attribute `addons` undefined. Which is true. Because it is set only when calling method `getAddons`.

Try this:

```
export class BackendServices {
  addons: IAddons[] = [];   
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.getWorkOrders();
  }
 getAddons() {
  return this.http.get<IAddons>(this.BASE_URL + '/addons/')
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.addons = data;
  });
}
```

Replacing

```
 addons: IAddons[];
```

with

```
 addons: IAddons[] = [];
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomislav. That seems to be in the right direction, In the component I have a button that calls a modal dialog and it is in the modal dialog constructor that I call the getAddons method, when i click on button the first time the dialog opens with nothing on it,, but when I click it second time it populates. How do we get around that.

Comment: How do I make the dialog open up only when the addons property has values loaded onto it.

Comment: It would be great if you could show some more code. But I suggest that, maybe, you extract your logic of calling `getAddons` from dialog constructor. Try calling your dialog after getting data from the server. But be aware that `getAddons` currently doesn't return anything and maybe it should return a `Promise`.

Comment: Thats  exactly what I am looking for. How do I make it to return a promise, not sure how to code it. As requested I have updated the post with more code.

Comment: Method `getAddons` just has to `return this.http.get()` because `$http.get()` method returns a promise itself. I will update my answer above.

Comment: Did you mean this way getAddons() {
      return this.http.get<IAddons>(this.BASE_URL + '/addons/')
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.addons = data;
      });
    }

Comment: Do you get any response from HTTP request? Maybe that is why after opening your popup `addons` is still empty.

Comment: That is what I am trying, how do I make sure that I get a response from HTTP before the dialog load happens.

Comment: It would be much easier to answer this if I could see whole classes :) Can you share them somehow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170968/discussion-between-tomislav-fabeta-and-sumchans).